# How to create custom Authentication Provider in DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I'm creating a site using DotNetNuke and need authenticate user via a WebService.
I don't know main idea to do this.

1. Need i create a custom login module? If true, after user pass
   validation by WebService, How DNN login for that user.
2. I see in "Admin\Site Settings\Login Settings". There is a combobox let me choose "Default Authentication Provider". Is there any way to create other Authentication Provider and bind it to that combo. After that i only select my custom authentication Provider.

I search on google in longtime but the results is not my expectation. Any body help me. Thanks all you :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest route is to create a custom authentication provider. This provider is a custom login control and from there you can after verifying the identity create the user within DNN. This is the typical method for this as it allows you to have a user in DNN that can have roles assigned to it etc.

I do have a "external database authentication provider" for sale in the DNN store which could serve as a good starting point for you. Sadly I'm not aware of any really detailed documentation on the process.

Comment: Thank Mitchel Sellers for your help. I done my job as your suggest.

Comment: If this helped be sure to mark as the answer if you don't mind!